# manually changing colors for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to manually change colors in ggplot so that my boxplots are color coded into groups (ex. Qilai and Nagigi same color). I ran the following code, and it worked just fine.

```
B1 <- ggplot(tissue_A, aes(x=Site, y=d15N.permil)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Suva", "Nagigi")), y_position = 14.3, map_signif_level=TRUE) +  
  geom_signif(comparisons=list(c("Suva", "Qilai")),
  y_position = 13.8, tip_length = 0.03, vjust=0.2, map_signif_level=TRUE)
```

I then tried to re-run it later, and everything works except for the colors. I changed the code to separate things out using the following code:

```
B1 + labs(title = "T. jarbua Tissue", y = "δ15 permil") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","yellow", "red","red"), name = "Site")

ggplot(tissue_A, aes(x=Site, y=d15N.permil)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Suva", "Nagigi")), y_position = 14.3, map_signif_level=TRUE) +  geom_signif(comparisons=list(c("Suva", "Qilai")), y_position = 13.8, tip_length = 0.03, vjust=0.2, map_signif_level=TRUE) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","yellow", "red","red"), name = "Site")
```

And am still having everything but the colors work. My R studio is up to date, and I have tried re-starting. Is there anything that might be preventing my code from running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing the `fill` argument when calling `aes`. See the following example from [this tutorial:](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually)

```
library(ggplot2)

ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
bp<-ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=dose)) +
  geom_boxplot()
bp
```

The following plot is produced, colored by dose.

[image: ToothGrowth coloured by dose]

You should add `fill=Site` when calling `aes`.

Comment: No problem. Consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/389333) if it helped you so people know the question is solved.